Ошибка NGINX 403 Forbidden
Первый раз размещаю фронт и бек на одном домене. При данной настройке на странице ошибка NGINX 403 Forbidden
server {
      listen 80;

      server_name ?da?h.fun www.?dac?.fun;

      root /path/path/frontend;

      location /api/ {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      }
}


Права установлены командой:
chmod +x /path/path/frontend 

Файл index.html присутствует в папке.

Читайте в логе ошибок почему 403

frontend/index.html" is forbidden (13: Permission denied),

Ну значит где-то права не выдали

drwxr-xr-x root www-data frontend
-rw-r--r-- root www-data index.html

Проверяйте все родительские каталоги

им тоже права от  www-data нужны? Все, что выше, root. Или имеются в виду вложенные во фронтенд папки?

Попробуй положить всё в /var/www/dac-fun, потом, chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/dac-fun.

Да, заработало, спасибо. В чём подвох? Из-за папки root?

Вполне логично, что к папке root не должен иметь доступ никто кроме собственно рута
